# How to move a file and change its creation time at the same time?

Tags: linux, files

If I move a file in Linux with the `mv` command, it moves the file but doesn't change its creation time to the current time. For that purpose, I have to separately use the `touch` command. So, is there a command that does both atomically?

I am interesting in doing this because I am using textFileStreaming in local mode (uses local file system instead of HDFS) with Spark, which requires atomic move of files in the streaming directory. If the time remains the same, as the original time for the moved file, the streaming program doesn't even notice it. It notices sure if through a script, I first move a file and then touch it to change its time. However, it could still happen, that the streaming program sees the file before its time was modified using touch, and thus ignore it.

Comment: Unix typically does not have a creation time. What filesystem is this, and what commands are you using?

Comment: Creation time, modification time or whatever you call it. The one that is displayed when you type ls -ll. My OS has ext4 filesystem. And like I said I am using 'mv' and 'touch'. But I want to do this in a single command, atomically that is.

Comment: What if you touch and then move?

Comment: That works too, but I still don't want that. Because maybe it take some time to move after the touch, and therefore the streaming handler still ignores it.

Comment: `rsync --remove-source-files SOURCEFILE DESTINATION/` will move your file _and_ update `mtime` (though `rsync` does use a hidden temporary file to do this...)

Answer (score 4):

`mv`, if you are working within the same filesystem, does not alter the file itself, only its location.  To alter the file, you *need* to use another utility such as `touch`, or to simply `cp` the file (which will create a new file with new modification and access times), and `rm` the old one.  If it's a particularly large file, this is inefficient, which is why tools like `touch` exist in the first place.

Alternatively, if the problem is atomicity, you can move the file to a temporary location, `touch` it, and then move it to its final resting place.